# Probabilities fall outside the differential?

Tags: probability, quantum-chemistry, born-rule

A few years ago I had a conversation with a physical chemist, and one of her comments still lingers in my memory. Our conversation was about Quantum Chemistry. In response to my commenting on the existence of Born's rule, and that the probabilities are non-negative by definition, she said something that perplexed me. If I remember correctly, she said "Sometimes the probabilities fall outside the differential". I do not understand this comment.

It is entirely possible that she misspoke, or I misheard, or that this phrasing does have a correct and precise meaning in Quantum Chemistry. Applying the [principle of charity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_charity), what is the most reasonable interpretation of this phrase in the above context?

Comment: would this answer your question?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function

Comment: @annav Unclear. I know what probability density functions are from the perspective of Kolmogorov's treatment of Probability Theory based on Measure Theory. Clearly there will be a differential in the integral, but I don't understand in what sense a probability would 'fall outside' of it.

Comment: Seeing the plots, they do have negative values in σ , on the x axis for low probabilities ,  I thought maybe in your then discussion the  (her?)confusion comes a plot like this.

Comment: @annav [Those $\sigma$ scores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#/media/File:Boxplot_vs_PDF.svg) would be the number of standard deviations from the mean for Gaussian distribution. Your suggestion is that the support variable(s) of a distribution can be negative, and that being negative is in some sense the probability being outside a differential? Could you unpack that more?

Comment: no, I am just trying to imagine how a chemist might confuse the probability distribution which has probability always positive, with negative numbers, if she has seen a similar plot.